# How can i parse local xml file instead of Web xml in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsxmlparser

Hii it's easy for me to parse a XML file from a web URL using NSXML Parser but i found little bit difficulty in parsing the local XML file.?

consider this,
my parser.m has a method for

```
-(void)parseRssFeed:(NSString *)url withDelegate:(id)aDelegate {
[self setDelegate:aDelegate];

responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSURL *baseURL = [[NSURL URLWithString:url] retain];


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURL];

[[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];}
```

and i used this method for calling a RSS Feed in one of my viewcontroller.m as

```
- (void)loadData {
if (items == nil) {
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];

    Parser *rssParser = [[Parser alloc] init];
    [rssParser parseRssFeed:@"http://--some RssFeed url---" withDelegate:self];

    [rssParser release];

} else {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}
```

and now instead of the some web Rss Feed Url i have to load my local XML file.
Please help me in this coding where i have to change and include NSBundlePath Resource for my local XML FIle.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a local file you don't need the `NSURLConnection` to get the data. The following will get a local XML file named "local.xml" into an `NSData` object:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"local" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

At this point you should be able to call the same parsing code you use once you have the data from the remote xml file.

Comment: hii rmaddy now i can load local XML file from my resource Directory but how can i pass the loaded content to my parser.m class ? i.e by using NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[data bytes]] ); i can see the loaded xml file but here i need to pass it to parser.m. Sorry i am new to this stuff can u help me ?