# How to load XML file from Xcode navigator locally - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, local

I know how to load an XML from a URL. But now I need to load an XML file locally.

I searched the internet but only found how to load XML file from "Documents Directory" (i.e. `NSString *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"xml"];`)

I don't know how to load XML file from Xcode navigator, like this:
[image: ScreenShot of Xcode]

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: [How to load](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13062577/3408316)
and
[NSData to NSString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411965/converting-nsdata-to-nsstring-in-objective-c)

Comment: @pandarencodemaster My bad. Thanks for the links. I didn't know that this: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"xml"]`  actually gets the file from Xcode navigator as well! I thought it only looks into the particular folder in the app's sandbox. Pleas correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not as well, but only fetches files from your Bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @pandaren codemaster for guiding me to the links he posted in the comment.

The code,

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"adml" ofType:@"xml"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

actually loads the **adml.xml** file from Xcode navigator locally, and converts into an `NSString` so we can verify the output too.

Problem solved.

Thanks again.